# Fastest Way to Find nearest indices between two sorted lists

Tags: performance-tuning, sorting, nearest

I have a sorted list of floats of length `n` and an `n` x `n` list of lists, where each nested list is are also sorted. I want to know the index of the element in `list` that is nearest to but less than each entry in `matrix` (essentially, the index in `list` after which to insert each element of `matrix`). For example, if `n=5`:

```
list=Sort@RandomReal[{-7,7},5]
matrix=Sort/@RandomReal[{-7,7},{5,5}]
```

For what I’m trying to do, `n` will be very large (on the order of 2000) and I will have to iterate over this many times, so the code needs to be as fast as possible. Right now, my method for doing this is to flatten the matrix (I won’t actually care about the matrix form in the end---all I want is the index for each entry) and using the following code:

```
OrdinalFunction[list1_,nearestFn_][list2_]:=With[{r=Flatten@nearestFn[list2]},r-UnitStep[list1[[r]]-list2]]
indexFn=OrdinalFunction[list,Nearest[list->"Index"]];

matrixElements=Flatten@matrix
indexFn[matrixElements]
```

The advantage of this code is that I can feed the entirety of `matrixElements` to `indexFn` to get the indices in `list` that are nearest to but less than each element. But the code makes no use of the fact that each list in `matrix` is sorted, and I feel that there must be a faster way to do this. Also, since the lists in `matrix` are sorted, once one of the elements returns the index of the last elements in ```list```, all subsequent elements will also return this index. Is there a way to take advantage of these facts to make it (ideally much) faster?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose that `a` and `b` are two sorted lists of real numbers of length `n` and `m`, respectively. The following `CompiledFunction` finds for each element `b[[j]]` in the second list the desired position in the first list:

```
cf = Compile[{{a, _Real, 1}, {b, _Real, 1}},
   Block[{i, bj, idx, n, m},
    n = Length[a];
    m = Length[b];
    idx = Table[0, m];
    i = 1;
    Do[
     bj = Compile`GetElement[b, j];
     While[(i <= n) && (Compile`GetElement[a, i] < bj),
      ++i;
      ];
     idx[[j]] = i - 1;
     , {j, 1, m}];
    idx
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];
```

It does so by at most $O(n+m)$ work. Algorithmically, it is similar to the merge step in merge sort.

I am not entirely sure what `Nearest[a->"Index"][b]` does in this case, but I believe it orders `a` (because it cannot know that it was ordered before) and then simply performs binary search in the array `a`. That would take $O( \log_2(n) \, m)$. So the algorithm in `cf` should be more efficient for large values of `n`. ( `n = 2000`) is actually rather small. A stronger advantage of `cf` is that both arrays are accessed in order, while binary search jumps around in `a`. So `cf` should

1. produce fewer cache misses (this is probably also irrelevant because `a` fits completely into L1 chache) and
2. be more predictable for the processor's branch prediction.

Plus `cf` is parallelized (but `Nearest` ist probably, too).

This is how the two algorithms compare on my 8-Core machine:

```
OrdinalFunction[list1_, nearestFn_][list2_] :=  With[{r = Flatten@nearestFn[list2]}, r - UnitStep[list1[[r]] - list2]];
indexFn = OrdinalFunction[list, Nearest[list -> "Index"]];
result = indexFn[Flatten@matrix]; // RepeatedTiming // First
result2 = cf[list, matrix]; // RepeatedTiming // First
ArrayReshape[result, {n, n}] == result2
```

> 0.0879834
>
> 0.00599676
>
> True

Hence, while `Nearest` requires $O(n^2 \, \log_2(n))$ work, `cf` should do all the job in $O(n ( n + n) ) = O(n^2)$. Things change when `list` has length `m` independent of `n`. Then `Nearest` requires $O(n^2 \, \log_2(m))$ and `cf` requires $O(n ( m + n) )$ work. The latter grows linearly in `m`, so `Nearest` should perform better, when `m` is several orders of magnitude greater than `n`.

Edit: Swapped the order of the checks `i <= n` and `` Compile`GetElement[a, i] < bj `` to prevent out-of-bounds reading of `a`.

Comment: Amazing! Just to clarify what the code is doing: when you write `cf[list,matrix]`, `cf` splits `matrix` into each of its sorted lists because of the specification `RuntimeAttributes->{Listable}`, correct? Also how could I write a similar code if I also wanted it to work for a sorted `list` and a `matrix` whose lists were reverse sorted? Like ```{7,5.1,0.2,-3,...}```.

Comment: Yes, it's exactly the `Listable` attribute that allows to "thread" through the rows of `matrix`; and because of `Parallelization -> True`, it does so in parallel. If the rows of `matrix` are reverse sorted, then you need only to reverse the `Do` loop, i.e., `Do[ ... , {i,m,1,-1}];`.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Quick follow-up: since we have `Parallelization->True` inside the compiled function, what would happen if I used `cf` in a piece of code that is inside, say, `ParallelTable`? I assume that there would be some kind of conflict over resources. Would `Parallelization` automatically be reset to `False` in `cf`, or would there still be a benefit to keeping this piece in?